# Differential equation with substitution - Second degree

Tags: ordinary-differential-equations, multivariable-calculus, partial-differential-equations, partial-derivative

Given:

$$f_{xx} = f_{yy}$$

I need to "translate" this equation to $v,u$ using the facts:

$v = x-y$ and $u = x+y$

But I don't know where to start really, all I've done is:
to say: $v+u = 2x \Rightarrow x = \frac{v+u}{2}$

$\frac{\partial^2 f}{\partial x^2} = \frac{\partial^2 f}{\partial (\frac{v+u}{2})^2}$ and so to $y$ as well..

But I am 100% sure it isn't going this way.. I would appreciate your help!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You want to use chain rule for this problem. First notice $$f_x=f_uu_x+f_vv_x=f_u+f_v$$ Continuing in this manner we get  $$f_{xx}=(f_u)_x+(f_v)_x=[f_{uu}u_x+f_{uv}v_x]+[f_{vu}u_x+f_{vv}v_x]=f_{uu}+2f_{uv}+f_{vv}$$
Similarly, $$f_y=f_uu_y+f_vv_y=f_u-f_v$$ And again,
$$f_{yy}=(f_u)_y-(f_v)_y=[f_{uu}u_y+f_{uv}v_y]-[f_{vu}u_y+f_{vv}v_y]=f_{uu}-2f_{uv}+f_{vv}$$ Equating these two equations gives $f_{uv}=0$ whose general solution is easily seen to be $$w=f_1(u)+f_2(v)$$ where $f_1,f_2$ are functions of a real variable. Hence $$f(x,y)=f_1(x+y)+f_2(x-y)$$ is the general solution to $f_{xx}=f_{yy}$.

Comment: So basically the translation of this equation for $x,y$ to $u,v$ is $ f_{uv} =0$ ? Or is it the solution: $ w = f_1 (u) + f_2(v)$ ? Thank you so much

Comment: The pde $f_{xx}=f_{yy}$ becomes $f_{uv}=0$ after performing the change of coordinates $u=x+y, v=x-y$

Comment: Hey, just a little question, why did you say that in the $f_{xx}$ line : $f_{uv} + f_{vu} = 2f_{uv}$ ? This isn't true everytime... so can we say that? or leave it as a different term?

And so the final answer is: $f_{uv} + f_{vu} = -f_{uv} - f_{vu}$ ? Thanks